# Android studio problem with configuration: type mismatach problem

Tags: android-studio

I wrote a code like that:

```
var btn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn)
```

view.findViewById(R.id.btn) is red underlined.
It's working fine but Android studio  tolds me that it is mismatch type (Compiler expected View!). It had been working fine until i changed a profile from debug to release. Since that it show me errors.

And one more error which i recived is with:

```
view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.user_name)
```

TextView is red underlined.
No type args expected for fun.

I belive that error s only becouse of android studio config. I can compile my code witout any problem, but android studio doesn't suggest me things like that.

Have you maybe any suggests ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to rebuild and clean your code? @Young_User

Might be an issue with what you are inheriting in your class.

Care to share the error code and full class too?

Comment: clean project helps